# Does there exists a homomorphism for any groups $G$ and $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a question from Exercise 8.2 of Visual Group Theory which says:determine whether true or false.

1. For any group $H$ and $G$,there is some homomorphism from $H$ to $G$.
2. For any groups $H$ and $G$, there is some embedding of $H$ into $G$. (Here embeddings means  homomorphism such that one group is subgroup of another).

Comment: Regard two different dihedral groups.

Comment: @Kaladin how can proving for tow particular groups be helpful in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** 1) $H \mapsto \{1\}$ is a homomorphism; 2) consider the case when $|H|>|G|$.

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract, suppose $H$ is bigger than $G$ (for example, in the sense of number of elements for finite groups). Can then $H$ be a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: a subgroup H of G has to have all the elements belonging to G.in your case when |H|>|G| it won't be possible.then what should I conclude.

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract: That not for *any* $H$ and $G$ there is an embedding. In particular, if $|H| > |G|$ then it won't be possible.

Comment: then 2) should be false.thanks.

Answer (score 3):

With questions as general as these, you can usually proceed by using two avenues. 
1) Look at general properties that are universal to everything. In this case it's the identity element that exists in every group.
2) Look at simple examples. For example remember/find some constructions of finite groups and then try to find homomorphisms and embeddings.